# Is there a way to get the input date format based on timezone?

Tags: javascript

The timezone looks like this:

```
{ value: 'Australia/Sydney',
  name: '(GMT+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney' },
```

The preferred date input format on that timezone is `DD/MM/YYYY`.

I will then use that as the date input format on jquery ui datepicker

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Or more accurately, I'll be passing the `DD/MM/YYYY` on `ui-date-format` attribute of angular-ui-date (which is based on jquery ui datepicker) https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date#ui-date-format-directive

I tried looking at [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) documentation, but I can't see anything there that can be passed of the timezone value `Australia/Sydney` and returns the date input format.

Comment: "Preferred format" and "timezone" are rather orthogonal. The "preferred format" can be language dependent, and in some timezones people speak more than one language.

Comment: I noticed that momentjs can be used to localize date based on timezone, e.g., `Australia/Sydney`, I'm thinking if momentjs has a reverse of it; that based on timezone, it can return the way the people input their dates

Answer (score -1):

Momentjs has a specific plugin for timezones: https://momentjs.com/timezone/
Data formats contains also Australian timezones (https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-formats/unpacked-format/)

For instance:

```js
    moment().tz("Australia/Sydney"); //.format();

    let now = moment(new Date()).format("L");

    console.log(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-utils.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think I already stated that I wanted the reverse. I need to get the date format to use for input, not for output